# Devise a streaming algorithm to verify whether a directed graph has a mother vertex?

Tags: algorithm, graph, streaming, space-complexity

I have the following question:

Given a directed graph G and a node S.
How can I devise a streaming algorithm to verify whether S node is a mother vertex?
(A Mother Vertex is a vertex through which we can reach all the other vertices of the Graph.)

How many time do I need to read the input of graph G to figure out the answer?

I don't know how to start with this problem.Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Sorry for not explaining what is a streaming algorithm. The following is the description of streaming algorithm.

"Streaming algorithm" are algorithms for processing data streams in which the input is presented as a sequence of items and can be examined in only a few passes (typically just one). In most models, these algorithms have access to limited memory (generally logarithmic in the size of and/or the maximum value in the stream). They may also have limited processing time per item.

Comment: What is a "streaming algorithm"?

Comment: @ravenspoint "streaming algorithm" are algorithms for processing data streams in which the input is presented as a sequence of items and can be examined in only a few passes (typically just one). In most models, these algorithms have access to limited memory (generally logarithmic in the size of and/or the maximum value in the stream). They may also have limited processing time per item.

Comment: You need to explain this in your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine if every vertex is reachable from S.  To do this, perform a depth first search and check that every vertex was visited.

Comment: Thank you! How can I analyze this algorithm's space complexity ?

Comment: The internet is full of analysis of the complexity of depth first searching algorithms